# Characterization of Sub-Gaussian RV

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

As per this [lecture notes](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/harchaoui/teaching/2013-2014/ensl/m2/lecture6.pdf), any random variable with $\mathbf{E}[X] = 0$ and $Var(X) \leq \sigma^2$ is a sub-gaussian RV.

The proof given there uses Fubini's theorem to deduce that
$ \sum_\limits{n \geq 0} t^n\frac{\mathbf{E}(X^n)}{n!} \leq \exp({\frac{t^2\sigma^2}{2}})$

I expanded the series on the LHS, but could not establish the inequality as LHS contains terms involving higher order moments of X. Any help on it ?

Comment: I couldn't find the proof which you are referring to in the link. Can you please point out the specific equation? Thanks.

Comment: @sudeep5221 sorry. Put the wrong link. Corrected the question with correct link

Comment: I think they just moved the higher order terms onto the right side and hid them using the $g(t)$ notation. $g(t)$ is then a convergent series with leading term of order $3$ or more, so $g(t)/t^2\to 0$ as $t\to 0$.

Comment: I think you have slightly misinterpreted the statement. It says that for subGaussian $X$ that satisfies $\mathbb{E}[\exp(tx)] \leq \exp(\sigma^2 t^2/2)$ we have the given relations on mean and variance and not the other way around. For the proof they first write the series expansion of $\exp(x)$ exchange the sum and integral using Fubini (since the expression is well defined) for the LHS. Then they expand RHS as well and combine the like terms and hide the higher order terms in $g(t)$.  From what I understand you are trying to prove the other way, which is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, the statement as you give it cannot hold. Here is a counter example.

Let $X$ be a real random variable with pdf equal to $$f(x) = \begin{cases}\tfrac{C}{x^4} & \text{if } |x|\geq 1\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ where $C$ is chosen so that $\int_\mathbb{R} f = 1$. Then by symmetry $\mathbb{E} X = 0$. Moreover, $$\sigma^2 = \mathbb{E}X^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus [-1,1]}\frac{Cx^2}{x^4} = 2C\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} = 2C.$$

On the other hand, the fourth moment $$\mathbb{E}X^4 = \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-1,1]} \frac{x^4}{x^4} = 2\int_1^\infty 1 = \infty.$$ This is impossible if $X$ was $2C$-sub Gaussian since if it was, symmetry ensures that $$\frac{1}{4!}\mathbb{E} X^4\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbb{E} X^{2n}}{(2n)!} =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbb{E} X^n}{n!} = \mathbb{E} e^{X} \leq e^{\tfrac{4C^2}{2}} = e^{2C^2},$$ or in other words that $$\infty = \mathbb{E} X^4 \leq 24 e^{2C^2},$$ a contradiction.